# Parsing timestamp in d3.js issues

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, timestamp

I am trying to parse a timestamp to use in a plot in `d3.js` but I cannot manage to get it to work. Examples of the timestamp are shown below:

```
 - 2022-02-17 09:52:37.000000
 - 2022-02-17 09:54:00.000000
```

The code that I use to do the parsing is:

```
`const dateParser = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = dateParser(d.ts);
    });`
```

Where `d.ts` is the timestamp

The output I get at the moment is under the form:

- `0NaN-NaN-NaN`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, *parsing* is the opposite of *formatting*: when you parse you convert a string to a date, while formatting is converting the date to a readable string (also, pay attention to your specifier, it's incorrect).

Therefore, you want `d3.timeParse()` instead. Here is the working snippet, look at your browser's console, not the snippet's one:

```js
const dates = ["2022-02-17 09:52:37",
  "2022-02-17 09:54:00"
];

const dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

dates.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(dateParser(d));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your dates strings? If so you could change your code to first convert the string date to Date object and then call dateParser on it:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = dateParser(new Date(d.ts));
});
```